# How to save last four results in a .txt file

Tags: python, file, text

I have been trying to save the last four results in a txt file.

```
Jim:4
Jim:6
Jim:5
Jim:0
Jim:2
```

Do I need to use collections in my program? My code is quite long so wont post on here.(yes/no)

Comment: This isn't really a good question because you're not describing your situation well. Are these four results input by a user? Are you just saving the numbers? Do you know how many results you have beforehand? You're not providing enough information.

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't need to use anything from the collections module to save four things to a file.

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open('myFile', 'w')
for i in [4,6,5,0,2]:
    f.write('%s:%d' % ('Jim', i))
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to the code. It is more important to communicate the underlying logic (alongside the code), so others can understand the reasoning, avoid similar issues, and adjust the code to fit their own needs.

Answer (score 0):

Hacky, unpythonic, brute force way to do it:

Stick your n results in a list:

```
results = []
x = 0
while x < n:
    results.append(yourfunction)
    x += 1
```

Then use a list comprehension to walk through your list backwards. That takes the form *list*[start:stop:step], so you start from -1 to get the last item, then it will go to the -5th item (the 4th to last), by increments of -1.

```
last4 = results[-1:-5,-1]
```

This will reverse your results, so if you need to keep them in order, reverse your last4 list by using the same idea:

```
rightorderlast4 = last4[-1::-1]
```

Leaving the stop blank in the comprehension will tell python to go to the end of the list and then stop.

Then make a writer:

```
for item in rightorderlast4:
    yourfilename.write("%s\n" % item)
```

And that should do it, with each item in your list of results on its own line in your text file. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Hey @khtad i would like to ask you a question?

Comment: @jimjohn What's your question?